# Is there any php/apache/mysql config limit in posting dynamically created input values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wamp

I have been developing an inventory application which works on both localhost and online. I use wamp for localhost environment.

In Wamp 2.2.21, dynamically created array values are saved completely and successfully. Pls refer below image link,

http://www.yemsolutions.com/wmp2.2.21.jpg

But after updating the latest version of wamp, 2.5/2.4, these arrays are posting only to a limit of 26 rows, i checked this many times various versions of wamp, and configurations. But still this works only upto wamp 2.2.21(apache 2.2.21, php 5.3.10, mysql 5.5.20). Refer image link below,

http://www.yemsolutions.com/wmplatest.jpg

Really stuck with this and request for help at the earliest

Really became nuts..

Comment: without code to see, there really isn't a way for us to give you an answer either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max_input_vars - on how many input fields

```
ini_set('max_input_vars', 3000);
```

Also theris php settings
php.ini

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

If you use Apache 
.htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```